# How to clear Tkinter canvas on button press

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, python-2.x, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a button that will clear a canvas and then put an image in the canvas selected from a Tkinter file dialog. I am using the `canvas.delete("all")` method [shared here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15840231/edit) to try clearing the canvas before selecting a new image, but the new image is appearing above the existing image rather than replacing it.

```py
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

canvas1 = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas1.pack()

class widgets:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent
        self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer1.pack()

        self.button1 = Button(self.myContainer1, command=self.button1click)
        self.button1.config(text="Select Image")
        self.button1.pack(side=TOP)

    def button1click(self):
        canvas1.delete("all")
        path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image File", '.png')])
        im = Image.open(path)
        tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        imglabel = Label(canvas1, image=tkimage)
        imglabel.image = tkimage
        imglabel.pack()

widgets = widgets(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you would have to use `create_image(... image=tkimage)` instead of `label.pack()` to put image on canvas - and then canvas can delete it. In current code you could use `label.pack_forget()` or `label.destroy()`. Or replace image in label.

Comment: Is there a reason you're packing a label into the canvas rather than creating an image item on the canvas (eg: `canvas.create_image(..)`)

Comment: Thank you! replacing ```label.pack()``` with ```canvas.create_image(..)``` solved the issue.